# Passing bool parameters to my script always results in the same output

Tags: powershell, parameters

So I'm working on a script and I would like to add an optional parameter. For some reason it doesn't work the way I thought it should, so clearly I'm not getting something here.

### I tried 2 methods:

#### Method 1

```
function Thing {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][bool]$StartThing
    )
    if ($StartThing -eq $true) {
        Write-Host "Thing started" -ForegroundColor Green
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "Thing didn't start" -ForegroundColor Red
    }
}

Thing
```

Then, I'm running: `.\test.ps1 -StartThing $true`

The output I'm getting is always `Thing didn't start`. No matter what value I pass in.

#### Method 2

I tried using `switch` instead in this form:

```
function Thing {
    param (
        [switch] $StartThing
    )
    switch ($StartThing) {
        $true { Write-Host "Thing started" -ForegroundColor Green }
        Default { Write-Host "Thing didn't start" -ForegroundColor Red }
    }
}

Thing -StartThing
```

This one doesn't work for me either. When I run `.\test.ps1 -StartThing` the output is always `Thing started`. I tried adding `$true` or `$false` inputs but the output is the same no matter what.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Any help would be great :)

Comment: On a side note, `[Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]` is obsolete because parameters default to non-mandatory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StartThing` is not being passed to your function. You always run is without any params (example from method 1, for method 2 the issue is similar):

```
Thing
```

If you want to run the file in the form provided, you need to add param block to the script file itself.

**NOTE:** Only relevant parts of code were added, I haven't changed the working parts. Please see [Olaf's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65991262/9902555) to improve the script even better:

```
# Param block for script
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][bool]$StartThing
)

function Thing {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][bool]$StartThing
    )
    if ($StartThing -eq $true) {
        Write-Host "Thing started" -ForegroundColor Green
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "Thing didn't start" -ForegroundColor Red
    }
}

# Function runs with the parameter provided
Thing -StartThing $StartThing
```

Comment: Thank you! I understand my mistake now. I tried doing the same fix with the `switch` parameter but it didn't work for some reason. I'll do some more research on this.

Thank you

Comment: BTW: `if ($StartThing -eq $true)` could be written shorter like this: `if ($StartThing)`

Answer (score 1):

This might clear it up a little:

```
function Thing {
    param (
        [switch] $StartThing
    )
    if ($StartThing) {
        "You provided the parameter 'StartThing'"
    }
    else {
        "You did not provide the parameter 'StartThing'"
    }
}
```

Now you simply run your function with

```
Thing -StartThing
```

And the result would be:

```
You provided the parameter 'StartThing'
```